# Cmake broken after update

Tags: apt, raspbian-stretch

Before running an `apt-get update`, my `cmake` worked. Now I get the error

```
    Setting up cmake (3.7.2-1) ...
pi@rpi:~ $ cmake
Segmentation fault
pi@rpi:~ $
```

And I can't compile any cmake files

I'm using Raspbian Strech

Comment: I have also tried re-install after running `purge --remove cmake* cmake-data*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a complete reinstall of Raspbian Stretch. Was the fastest thing to do.

Comment: But that is the solution I provided in my answer. Or do you mean you reinstalled complete Raspbian Stretch?

Comment: Complete reinstall of raspbian

Answer (score 1):

You should do a clean update/full-upgrade, purge and install cmake:

```
pi ~$ sudo -Es
root ~# apt update
root ~# apt full-upgrade
root ~# apt purge cmake
root ~# apt autoremove
root ~# apt install cmake
root ~# exit
pi ~$
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and maybe you have a solution, but I developed this problem recently while trying to build ROS on Raspbian Stretch. I may need to do a `dist-upgrade` or something, but I'm trying not to change my config too much for other reasons.

I tried following Ingo's purge-and-reinstall, and it didn't work.

So I downloaded and bootstrap-built cmake 3.12.3 from source and that seems to have fixed it.

Comment: I gave up and reinstalled

Comment: @shaggs Please create an answer and accept it after two days. Only this will finish your question. Otherwise it will pop up again and again for years and others try to help you for nothing.